# How can i use “x-ms-meta-name:value” in Microsoft azure integration

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('PUT');
req.setHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
req.setHeader('x-ms-date', timestamp);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
req.setHeader('x-ms-version', '2015-12-11'); // TODO: 2019-07-07
req.setHeader('Content-Length', fileLength);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType);
// see sample here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob
req.setHeader('x-ms-meta-patientFileId', patientFileId);
req.setEndpoint(fileUrl);
req.setBodyAsBlob(fileBody);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

when i send request i get System.HttpResponse[Status=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature., StatusCode=403]

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details like for instance when this is precisely happening or give some more context, please.

Comment: I believe the problem is with creation of `authHeader`. Please share the code for creation of that.

Comment: when i remove 'req.setHeader('x-ms-meta-patientFileId', patientFileId);' its working fine

Comment: @Rijwandeltax any new on this ? I created the request using postman with a SAS token and it works fine